# How to Manually install magento extensions and themes?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I tired of searching in google and also in MSE but didn't find the exact way of installing magento extensions and themes MANUALLY as I use LINUX I cannot able to install through Magento Connect manager so please someone help me with this and also Iam getting error 503.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok lets solve this.

Step 1 :search for required extension/Theme and get the extension key and copy it.

Step 2:Now paste it in [here to download](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php?)

Step 3:Copy the folders and paste them into your Magento root folder but dont forget to merge them.

your theme/extension  is now ready to use hope this helps

Comment: Also you will want to make sure the permissions are correct on those new files plus the directories. Otherwise you can have the 'downloader' screen show (e.g. if the 'app' folder gets chmodded to something weird.)

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the extesion files over your magento instance and make sure the folder names overlap.
extension `app` goes over magento `app`, `skin` over `skin` and so on.
Nothing should be overwritten. If it is, then something is wrong with the extension.
When you are done clear the cache.
But please explain more on what do you mean by "as I use LINUX I cannot able to install through Magento Connect ". Magento connect should work independent of the OS.

Comment: It is being strucked after some process and when I cancel it and load my admin dashboard or my site it is showing some error 503 dude to maintanence.flag file in my magento's root.

Comment: Just don't check the checkbox for maintenance mode when installing an extension

Comment: Thanks this solved my 503 error but still no extension is available in my admin dashboard but the above manual installation process worked thanks for that voting up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Open the admin panel, go to System --> Cache Management and Disable all the cache.

Get the extension key of your selected Magento theme or extension from Magento Connect manager.

Go to System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager and paste the Key of your theme or extension. Now just install it.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Search` for the extension that you want to Install
2. `Download` the Extension files.
3. Open the `zip/tar` file and make sure all the folders in the extension overlap to your magento root directory folders.
4. Connect to your Host using FTP Client and `copy` the zip/tar file in the root directory of Magento.
5. Connect to your Host using ssh and `extract` the extension zip/tar file.

> $ tar -xvzf extension.tar.gz

Now **delete** the `var/cache` folder through ftp or ssh.

**Revisit your url and the extension will be successfully installed.**